# Shiny app with multiple input modules that creates the same output

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinymodules, googlesheets4

I have an Shiny app where the users upload data to be processed. The user can choose a data source (like a file or a connection to a cloud service like google sheets). The number of types of data sources will increase in future. My plan was to make a module for every type of data source (local files, cloud services, databases, etc.). The problem is that everything has to go to the same object in output. I cannot seem to get this working with modules. Below is an example that doesn't work.

```
library(shiny)
library(googlesheets4)

# Google Sheets module
read_google_sheets_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- shiny::NS(id)
  shiny::tagList(
    shiny::textInput(ns("google_txt"), "Enter google identifier:")
  )
}

read_google_sheets_server <- function(input, output, session, rv, iid = NULL){
  ns <- session$ns
  txtnm <- paste0(ifelse(is.null(iid), "", paste0(iid, "-")), "google_txt")
  chosenURL <- reactive({
    validate(need(input[[txtnm]], message = "No URL selected"))
    print("txtnm is:", txtnm)
    input[[txtnm]]
  })

  chosenGS <- reactive({
    ID <- as_sheets_id(chosenURL())
    read_sheet(ID)
  })
  return(chosenGS())
}

# File reading module
load_all_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  shiny::tagList(
    fileInput(inputId = ns("fn"), label = "Choose your file"),
    actionButton("laai", label = "Load")
  )
}

load_all_server <- function(input, output, session, rv, iid = NULL){
  ns <- session$ns
  fnn <- paste0(ifelse(is.null(iid), "", paste0(iid, "-")), "fn")
  chosenD <- reactive({
    shiny::validate(need(input[[fnn]], message = "No file selected"))
    dp <- as.character(input[[fnn]]$datapath)
    print("\ndp is: ", dp)
    rio::import(file = dp, setclass = "data.frame")
  }, domain = session)
  chosenD()
}
```

Now make a module that calls the appropriate data-loading modulde depending on the choice of the user

```
# Module UI
multi_source_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  shiny::tagList(
    selectInput(inputId = ns("input_type_select"), 
                label = "Choose data input type", 
                choices = c("File" = "file", 
                            "Cloud" = "cloud")
    ), 
    uiOutput(ns("multiUI"))
  )
}

# Module Server
multi_source_server <- function(input, output, session){
  ns <- session$ns
  filelist <- list(fileInput(inputId = "fn", label = "Choose your file!!!"), 
                   actionButton(inputId = "fn_go", label = "Load file"))
  googlelist <- list(textInput("google_txt", "Enter google identifier:"),
                     actionButton(inputId = "google_go", label = "Load from Google Sheet"))

  output$the_ui <- eventReactive(
    eventExpr = input$input_type_select,
    valueExpr = ifelse(input$input_type_select == "file", 
                       tagList(filelist),
                       tagList(googlelist))
  )
}

multi_source_data <- function(input, output, session, rv, iid ){
  ns <- session$ns
  observeEvent(ns(input$google_txt), { rv$the_data <- callModule(read_google_sheets_server, id = iid, iid = iid)})
  observeEvent(ns(input$fn$datapath),{ rv$the_data <- callModule(load_all_server, id = iid)})
}
```

Test the approach

```
# Test
multi_source_test <- function(){
  uii <- fluidPage(
    multi_source_ui("id1"), 
    uiOutput("multiUI"),
    h2("The data"),
    tableOutput("multidata")
  )

  serverr <- function(input, output, session){
    the_ui <- callModule(multi_source_server, "id1")
    the_data <- callModule(module = multi_source_data, id = "id2", rv = rv, iid = "id1")
    # outputs
    output$multiUI <- renderUI({ the_ui() })
    output$multidata <- renderTable({ the_data() })
  }

  shinyApp(uii, serverr, options =list(test.mode = TRUE))
}
```

I want the user to be able to choose either a file or a google sheet and the data to be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a working, but quite modified, version of your application. A few comments:

1. What you are trying to do with `txtnm <- paste0(ifelse(is.null(iid), "", paste0(iid, "-")), "google_txt")` and `fnn <- paste0(ifelse(is.null(iid), "", paste0(iid, "-")), "fn")` is unnecessary - Shiny's namespace functionality handles all of that on your behalf. Consequently, I have removed those lines of code; I have also removed the 'iid' parameters from functions 'read_google_sheets_server' and 'load_all_server', as you do not seem to use the arguments passed to the 'iid' parameters for anything else.
2. Extracting the namespace in 'read_google_sheets_server' and 'load_all_server' (as you are doing by `ns <- session$ns`) serves no purpose. It is usually only necessary when you want to use uiOutput/renderUI in your module (e.g. as in your "multi_source" module); I have therefore removed the `ns <- session$ns` calls from 'read_google_sheets_server' and 'load_all_server'.
3. I added an actionButton to 'read_google_sheets_ui', identical to the one you had in 'load_all_ui', to prevent code in 'load_all_server' from being executed with every character typed into the textInput.
4. I renamed "load_all_" to "read_file_" to minimise confusion.
5. There is generally no need to wrap calls to input$... in a reactive statement if you really just want to extract the value of an input item, because 'input' is inherently reactive. Since we have added an actionButton to 'read_google_sheets_ui' and moved the `validate(need(...))` statement there, the code for determining 'chosenURL' can thus be simplified to `chosenURL <- input[["google_txt"]]`
6. In module 'load_all_ui' (which I renamed to 'read_file_ui') you forgot to wrap the ID of the actionButton in a call to ns().
7. Your 'load_all_server' (which I renamed to 'read_file_server') lacked an observeEvent for the actionButton which you put in the module's UI.
8. Things derailed a bit in module "multi_source" and the code for the ui and server functions of the app itself, so I combined the code for that module with the code for the app (for starters, it seemed like you intended to render either a 'read_google_sheets_ui' or a 'read_file_ui' for uiOutput "multiUI", but the tag lists that you constructed contained neither of those components).
9. I think it may help you a lot to carefully read through the following article: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

---

```
library(shiny)
library(googlesheets4)

read_google_sheets_ui <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(
        textInput(ns("google_txt"), "Enter google identifier:"),
        actionButton(ns("laai"), label = "Load")
    )
}

read_google_sheets_server <- function(input, output, session){

    chosenGS <- reactiveVal()

    observeEvent(input$laai, {
        validate(need(input[["google_txt"]], message = "No URL selected"))
        chosenURL <- input[["google_txt"]]
        ID <- as_sheets_id(chosenURL)
        chosenGS(read_sheet(ID))
        #chosenGS(data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, x = c(1:4), y = 5:8))
    })

    return(chosenGS)
}

read_file_ui <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    shiny::tagList(
        fileInput(inputId = ns("fn"), label = "Choose your file"),
        actionButton(inputId = ns("laai"), label = "Load")
    )
}

read_file_server <- function(input, output, session){

    chosenD <- reactiveVal()

    observeEvent(input$laai, {
        validate(need(input[["fn"]], message = "No file selected"))
        dp <- as.character(input[["fn"]]$datapath)
        chosenD(rio::import(file = dp, setclass = "data.frame"))
    })

    return(chosenD)
}

uii <- fluidPage(

    selectInput(inputId = "input_type_select", 
                label = "Choose data input type", 
                choices = c("File" = "file", 
                            "Cloud" = "cloud")), 
    uiOutput("multiUI"),

    h2("The data"),
    tableOutput("multidata")
)

serverr <- function(input, output, session){

    theData <- reactiveVal(NULL)

    output$multiUI <- renderUI({

        switch(input$input_type_select,
               file = read_file_ui(id = "readFile_ui"),
               cloud = read_google_sheets_ui(id = "readGS_ui"))
    })

    observeEvent(input$input_type_select, {
        theData(switch(input$input_type_select,
                       file = callModule(read_file_server, id = "readFile_ui"),
                       cloud = callModule(read_google_sheets_server, id = "readGS_ui")))
    })

    output$multidata <- renderTable({ theData()() })
}

shinyApp(uii, serverr, options = list(test.mode = TRUE))
```